# Correct syntax for multiline search and replace in perl so non-matching lines aren't printed

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to do a multiline search and replace but can't quite get it right that only what I need is outputted.

I want to extract the time from each line that directly follows a dashed line so this input:

```
--------------------
2016-05-13 10:00:00 abc
2016-05-13 10:00:01 def
2016-05-13 10:00:02 ghi
--------------------
2016-05-13 10:00:03 jkl
2016-05-13 10:00:04 mno
```

should produce output like this:

```
10:00:00
10:00:03
```

This command does seem to correctly replace in every match, however it also prints the rest of the line and every line that doesn't match.

```
perl -0ne 'print if s/-{20}\n\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d (\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)/$1/g'
```

Adding `.*` at the end of the regex doesn't help much as it only removes the rest of the line after the match and adding `/s` makes the command output only the very first replaced match.

How to get only the needed output?

**EDIT:**

Sobrique's answer utilizes the dashed line (or part of it) as a record separator but I'm also interested in how would I obtain the required data if the dashed line was **after** the needed output.

Let's say I wanted `10:00:02` from the above input, i.e. the equivalent of matching the backreference in the regex `^\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d (\d\d:\d\d:\d\d).*\n-{20}` (the caret not too important there, I believe). I could just use `tac` before and after executing Sobrique's solution but would like to see how to achieve this without doing it.

Comment: Why `10:00:02`? I think it should be `10:00:03`. Am I right?

Comment: @Shafizadeh Oops, yes. Typo while editing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so what you need to know is this:

`-0` sets the record separator. You probably don't want to do this.

`-n` tells perl to iterate STDIN (or files specified) in a way quite similar to how grep/sed/awk would.

And `-e` specifies code to run.

What's happening in *your* code though, means that *if* that pattern match tests, perl is printing the 'whole block' - which is the whole file.

I would suggest instead what you want is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings; 

local $/ = '--'; 
while ( <DATA> ) {
   print $1,"\n" if m/ (\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)/;
}

__DATA__
--------------------
2016-05-13 10:00:00 abc
2016-05-13 10:00:01 def
2016-05-13 10:00:02 ghi
--------------------
2016-05-13 10:00:03 jkl
2016-05-13 10:00:04 mno
```

Or as a one liner:

```
perl -ne 'BEGIN { $/ = "--" } print $1,"\n" if m/ (\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)/'
```

What this does instead, is iterate a 'chunk' at a time, based on '--' being a record separator, and then just grabs the first instance of a 'time-like' format within each chunk.

To answer your follow on question - if you wanted to catch the *last* time in the block, then I'd probably do it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings; 

local $/ = '--'; 
while ( <DATA> ) {
   my @matches = m/ (\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)/g ;
   print $matches[-1],"\n" if @matches;
}

__DATA__
--------------------
2016-05-13 10:00:00 abc
2016-05-13 10:00:01 def
2016-05-13 10:00:02 ghi
--------------------
2016-05-13 10:00:03 jkl
2016-05-13 10:00:04 mno
```

Capture all the regex matches on (time like) strings, into a list, then print the last element.

Matches contains:

```
$VAR1 = [
          '10:00:00',
          '10:00:01',
          '10:00:02'
        ];
```

And

```
$VAR1 = [
          '10:00:03',
          '10:00:04'
        ];
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Could the `$/` be set to some equivalent of the regex `^-{20}$`? In this form if some line contained the text `------- 10:00:00` it would be in the output.

Comment: `local $/ = "\n"."-"x20;` - `$/` doesn't do regex, but just literal text.

Comment: Hmm, how would that look like in the one-liner? Also, please see the edit.

Comment: It would look a lot like that in the one liner. `BEGIN { $/ = "\n"."-"x20 }`.

Comment: For some reason it didn't work for me before, did a mistake somewhere, I suppose. Thanks again.